# Rig really Laggy

Tags: modeling, rigging, multiresolution

Im working on making 2 fully rigged human models. The second model has even more polygons,(100k for this one and 220k for the second one) and for some reason this one is significantly more laggy than the other one when posing. They are both using multiple multiresolution modifiers so I was thinkint it was that but honesty im not sure what it is as of this moment
[image]
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1) Base vert count doesn't matter.  Vert count going into armature matters.  This is 100k verts base, and multi-res makes more.  2) Is that particle hair?  That's slow.  3) Armature performance is number of vertex-influences-- a vert with 6 deforming weights takes three times as long to pose as a vert with 2.  4) Can't really begin to give definitive answers without files.